# SQL Loop based calculation

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have following data:

[image: Data]

Calculation is the column consists of following formula:

```
For Exmaple H12 = =(C12-D12+C12-E12+C12-F12+C12-G12)
                  +(D12-C12+D12-E12+D12-F12+D12-G12)
                  +(E12-C12+E12-D12+E12-F12+E12-G12)
                  +(F12-C12+F12-D12+F12-E12+F12-G12)
                  +(G12-C12+G12-D12+G12-E12+G12-F12)
```

In short for category 1, (col1 value i.e. 2 minus col1 value) into  (col1 value minus value for rest columns) by keeping col1 as fix then Plus same for col2.

Additional conditions are there can be any number of columns (cols) and any number of categories.
So I have attempted to write a code. But how to write a calculation part?:

```
DECLARE @i int = 0 
DECLARE @j int = 0
DECLARE @k int = 1
DECLARE @Category_Count int = (select count(distinct Category) from Table) --This I am getting some other table
DECLARE @columns int = (select count(distinct columns) from Table) --This I am getting some other table

WHILE @i < @Category_Count 
BEGIN
    WHILE @j < @columns 
    BEGIN
        WHILE @k < @Category_Count 
        BEGIN
            /* Calculation=
            How to write this part */
            SET @k = @k + 1
        END
        SET @j = @j + 1
    END

    SET @i = @i + 1
END
```

Comment: I don't understand what you're actually asking here, however, you look to be thinking programmatically here. SQL isn't a programming language, it's a query langiage and *should* be written with Set-Based Solutions, not iterative ones. Having a `WHILE` inside a `WHILE` is a sure sign to have some *very* slow code.

Comment: If you take a closer look to the H12 formula, you'll see that each column is listed 4 times with + and 4 times with -. So H12 will always have 0 as value. Please review the question and explain better what you are looking for.

Comment: Nice spot, @NicolaLepetit . Completely agree, this is "nonsense" math effectively, as it results in [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JWEBS.png).

Comment: @Larnu Correct but I wanted to achieve this in SQL Hence the question.

Comment: So wouldn't you just replace `C12` with `Col1`, `D12` with `Col2`, ... `G12` with `Col6`?

Comment: From your question i can see alternate +ves and -ves. Get the column numbers using below query 

    (select max(column_id) from sys.tables t inner join sys.columns c on t.object_id = c.object_id
    where t.name ='table_name')

Iterate upto column length and do operations alternate on columns. 
Then sum all rows.

Answer (score 0):

```
create table #tab1
(
Category varchar(1),
col1 int,
col2 int,
col3 int,
col4 int,
col5 int,
Calculation int
)

insert into #tab1 values('a',2,3,1,1,3,0),('b',1,3,3,3,2,0),('c',12,5,4,2,6,0),('d',2,3,4,3,2,0),('e',2,1,2,1,1,0),('f',2,3,1,2,2,0),('g',2,3,1,1,3,0),('h',2,3,1,1,3,0),('i',2,3,1,1,3,0),
('j',2,3,1,1,3,0)


DECLARE @count int = 0 
DECLARE @j int = 0
DECLARE @k int = 1

select row_number() over(order by category) as RN,* into #tab2 from #tab1
select @count=count(*) from #tab1


WHILE (@k <= @count) 
BEGIN

    update  #tab2 set Calculation=
            ((col1-col2+col1-col3+col1-col4+col1-col5)
           +(col2-col2+col2-col3+col2-col4+col2-col5)
           +(col3-col2+col3-col2+col3-col4+col3-col5)
           +(col4-col2+col4-col2+col4-col3+col4-col5)
           +(col5-col2+col5-col2+col5-col3+col5-col4))
           from #tab2 where RN= @k

   set @k=@k+1
END
```

Comment: Thanks for the effort but this does not deal with the requirement `there can be any number of columns (cols) and any number of categories`. The only answer that would work is by using dynamic SQL, not fixed SQL. Please update your answer to use dynamic SQL, or else please consider removing it.

Comment: Okay Sure. I tried and definitely this works. Are you trying for dynamic columns?

Comment: do you really need it?